# OpenCV (C++) - whitenning transformation on a color image

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

Is there a built-in function to apply a whitening transformation on a `cv::Mat` with 3 channels? 
I want the image to have a *zero mean* and a *unit variance*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cv::Mat Whiten(cv::Mat image)
{
    image.convertTo(image, CV_32F);

    cv::Mat mu, sigma;
    cv::meanStdDev(image, mu, sigma);

    std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
    cv::split(image, channels);
    for (int i = 0; i < channels.size(); ++i)
        channels[i] = (channels[i] - mu.at<double>(i, 0)) / sigma.at<double>(i, 0);
    cv::merge(channels, image);

    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest option to what you want (that I'm aware of) is using `cv::meanStdDev` (it can handle multi-channel images) and then manually subtracting the mean and dividing by variance each channel.